# Evaluate: $\int \sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+...\infty}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the Integral: $\displaystyle\int \sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+...\infty}}}dx$, where $\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+...\infty}}}$ is a convergent infinitely nested radical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I=\displaystyle\int \sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+...\infty}}} dx$$
Let, $\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+\sqrt{2x+...\infty}}}=u\implies \sqrt{2x+u}=u\implies dx=\dfrac{2u-1}{2}du$
$$\implies I=\displaystyle \int u\cdot \bigg(\dfrac{2u-1}{2}\bigg)du$$
$$\implies I=\displaystyle \int u^{2}-\dfrac{u}{2}du$$
$$\implies I=\displaystyle \int u^{2}-\int \dfrac{u}{2}du$$
$$\implies I=\dfrac{u^{3}}{3}-\dfrac{u^{2}}{4}+C$$

Comment: Please, write the expression of $u(x)$ in your answer.$$u(x)=\begin{cases}\quad0\qquad\qquad\;\,\text{ if }x=0\\\\\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+8x}}2\quad\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Antonio I think there is no need of writing it

Comment: If you wrote it, you could get an explicit form for the integral, moreover we would certainly know that the expression containing the nested roots is convergent for all $x\geqslant0$.

Comment: Sorry, but i am not that much well-versed with latex coding. Can you please tell the latex code for that expression.